# How do I solve the "server DNS address could not be found" error on Windows 10?

Tags: dns, server, windows-10

After installing Windows 10, I am continuously getting the "**server DNS address could not be found**" error.

I will be able to use the Internet for 4-5 minutes, and after that for 20-25 min I will get the above error.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: It keeps on happen every day.

Comment: If it happens suddenly in **Google Chrome** for no apparent reason, just clear the DNS cache in both the browser and Windows. [See "Method 2" here.](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/solved-server-dns-address-could-not-be-found/)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

There might be a problem with your DNS servers of the [ISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_service_provider). A computer by default uses the ISP's DNS servers. You can manually configure your DNS servers. It is free and usually better than your ISP.

1. Go to Control Panel → Network and Internet → Network and Sharing Centre
2. Click on Change Adapter settings.
3. Right click on your connection icon (Wireless Network Connection or Local Area Connection) and select properties.
4. Select Internet protocol version 4.
5. Click on "Use the following DNS
   server address" and type either of the two DNS given below.

#### Google Public DNS

```
Preferred DNS server : 8.8.8.8
Alternate DNS server : 8.8.4.4
```

#### OpenDNS

```
Preferred DNS server : 208.67.222.222
Alternate DNS server : 208.67.220.220
```

Comment: I'm curious to learn... how does this randomly happen one morning? I'm guessing it's an ISP thing since I've changed nothing, but what is happening? Curious to learn more, thanks!

Comment: @james By default the system uses ISP DNS servers. So there will be problem with your ISP DNS servers at that time. You will be able to ping any IP, but you won't be able to browse websites because the hostname cannot be resolved. It's better to configure google DNS (8.8.8.8) or open DNS as they will be better than ISP DNS.

Comment: What if I have linux?  (Ubuntu).

Comment: can u please elaborate ,what u mean by `It is free and usually better than your ISP.` 
How is it better ?

Comment: This proved a temporary fix for me.

Comment: simply restarting/reset the router(dongle) works for me.

Answer (score 28):

Steps to manually configure DNS:

1. You can access Network and Sharing center by right clicking on the Network icon on the taskbar.
2. Now choose adapter settings from the side menu.
3. This will give you a list of the available network adapters in the system . From them right click on the adapter you are using to connect to the internet now and choose properties option.
4. In the networking tab choose ‘Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)’.
5. Now you can see  the properties dialogue box showing the properties of IPV4. Here you need to change some properties.

   Select ‘use the following DNS address’ option. Now  fill the following fields as given here.

   Preferred DNS server: `208.67.222.222`

   Alternate DNS server : `208.67.220.220`

   This is an available [Open DNS address](https://use.opendns.com/). You may also use [google DNS server addresses](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/).

   After filling these fields. Check the ‘validate settings upon exit’ option. Now click OK.

*You have to add this DNS server address in the  router configuration also (by referring the router manual for more information).*

Refer : [for above method & alternative](http://merabheja.com/dns-server-not-responding-in-windows-10/)

If none of this works, then open command prompt(Run as Administrator) and run these:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /registerdns
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
NETSH winsock reset catalog
NETSH int ipv4 reset reset.log
NETSH int ipv6 reset reset.log
Exit
```

Hopefully that fixes it, if its still not fixed there is a chance that its a NIC related issue(driver update or h/w).

Also FYI, this has a thread on Microsoft community : [Windows 10 - DNS Issue](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_web/windows-10-dns-issue/693c1d3a-5a3d-4138-b21a-3202db018789)

Comment: I'm curious to learn... how does this randomly happen one morning? I'm guessing it's an ISP thing since I've changed nothing, but what is happening? Curious to learn more, thanks!

Comment: I think it comes with windows update. I had auto update enabled on my machine and one day out of nowhere it keeps happening to me. My router works fine and it connects without issues with my Android phone so it has to either chrome or windows. I tried using Firefox but I faced the same issue that means it has to be my OS.

Comment: Helped a lot thanks

Comment: When you run netsh commands, one will be prompted to restart the machine, In my experience, DNS changes will be resolved before the restart.