# DNS Lookup for "www.xxxxxxxxxx.co.uk" failed with Dns 8.8.8.8

Tags: .net, dns, web, cloud-hosting, dyndns

I can access the website if I have dynamic ip address but it failed to browse when I have static IP. Here is the response I am getting when I ping the url.

"DNS Lookup for "www.xxxxxxxxxx.co.uk" failed. This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server"
Static dns : 8.8.8.8

Earlier I have gone thorugh "[How to solve "server DNS address could not be found" error in windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36668374/how-to-solve-server-dns-address-could-not-be-found-error-in-windows-10)" this link but still I really want to know  why it's not working with 8.8.8.8

Answer (score 1):

This'll be your issue. Looks like the attacks ramping down.

http://thenextweb.com/security/2016/10/21/massive-ddos-attack-dyn-dns-causing-havoc-online/

https://map.norsecorp.com/#/